# How can I avoid using multiple SQL calls to get data?

Tags: sql, join, left-join

I have a MySQL database, in which I have a table of `monkeys`:

```
id     name
1      Alice
2      Bill
3      Donkey Kong
4      Edna
5      Feefee
```

I also have a table of `bananas` and where they were picked from.

```
id     where_from
1      USA
2      Botswana
3      Banana-land
4      USA
```

Finally, I have a table `matches` that describes which bananas belong to which monkeys. Each monkey can only have one banana, and no monkeys can share a banana. Some monkeys may lack a banana.

```
id     monkey_id     banana_id
1      3             4 
2      4             1
3      5             2
```

How can I use a single SQL statement to retrieve all the matches? For each match, I want the name of the monkey as well as where the banana is from.

I have tried the following 3 SQL statements, which work:

1. `SELECT * FROM matches`
2. `SELECT * FROM monkeys WHERE id=[monkey_id from 1st SQL query]`
3. `SELECT * FROM bananas WHERE id=[banana_id from 1st SQL query]`

I feel that 3 SQL statements is cumbersome though. Any ideas on how I can just use a single SQL statement? I am just learning SQL and am monkeying around with the basics. Thanks!

Comment: You are looking for a `JOIN`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since *some monkeys may lack a banana*, that implies [a `LEFT JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join) between `matches` and `monkeys`. That will ensure all monkeys are listed, even if they have no bananas in `matches`.

```
SELECT
  monkeys.name,
  bananas.where_from
FROM
  monkeys
  /* List all monkeys, even if they have no match */
  LEFT JOIN matches ON monkeys.id = matches.monkey_id
  /* And another LEFT JOIN to link matches to bananas */
  LEFT JOIN bananas ON bananas.id = matches.banana_id
```

[Here is an example on SQLfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/78812/2)

I very highly recommend reading over Jeff Atwood's (co-founder of Stack Overflow) [excellent article explaining SQL joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).